# Only one function for both addition and subtraction

Tags: javascript, node.js

I trying to create one function that take two parameters and return both addition and subtraction.This is what I tried.

```
function two(num1,num2){
console.log(num1 +num2);
console.log(num1 -num2);
}
```

Can I solve this problem other than this method

Comment: FWIW, your function is not returning anything at the moment. Functions in JavaScript can only return a single value, but there is one value that is composed of one or more other values: objects (and a special type of object: arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Return an object with both results:

```js
function two(num1, num2) {
  return {
    sum: num1 + num2,
    diff: num1 - num2
  };
};
console.log(two(10, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function two(n1, n2) {
  return {
    addition: n1 + n2,
    subtraction: n1 - n2
  };
};

var {addition , subtraction} = two(15,10);
console.log(addition);
console.log(subtraction);
```